# Magmi is creating simple and configurable products without association

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm trying to associate simple products with configurable ones. My CSV file looks like this:

```
"attribute_set","type","sku","name","color","configurable_attributes","simples_skus"
"Default","simple","test011","Test product 1","Blue","color",""
"Default","simple","test012","Test product 2","Green","color",""
"Default","simple","test013","Test product 3","Red","color",""
"Default","simple","test014","Test product 4","Black","color",""
"Default","configurable","test010","Test product","","color","test011,test012,test013,test014"
```

After processing this file I'm getting all the products fine but when I edit configurable one I'm getting page where I have to choose super attribute for it like in image below:

[image: Magento configurable product create page]

Edit ...

After enabeling     "Configurable Item processor" still there is no association of simple products. See image below:

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Make sure to enable configurable attribute processor setting in magmi configuration.

Comment: True, I have enabled grouped instead of configurable. My bad :( but still there are no association of simple products. Check update.

Comment: You can try by adding store and websites columns. Also please try assigning them manually.

Comment: You don't have to add store or websites columns without them products are assigned to all stores, websites etc. While associating products manually everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "Configurable Item processor" configuration items have to be in this list:

```
1. CFGR:simplesbeforeconf = "0"
2. CFGR:updsimplevis = "0"
3. CFGR:nolink = "0"
```

Otherwise it wasn't working probably code goes like the list above.

Regards,